# Funcionamento @classmethod

Tags: python, python-2.7

Gostaria de entender melhor a anotação @classmethod do Python.

Resumidamente funciona como uma segunda alternativa para construtor. Porém, quais os benefícios? Quando utilizar?

```
@classmethod
def from_teste(cls, teste):
```

Qual o funcionamento do `cls` ?

Comment: "funciona como uma segunda alternativa para construtor" como assim? Métodos de classe (e métodos estáticos) não têm relação nenhuma com construtores, que eu saiba... (*um* método de classe - o `__new__` - tem envolvimento com a criação de objetos, mas o resto não tem nada a ver) P.S. Acabei de perceber que algumas pessoas *usam* métodos de classe como construtores alternativos (métodos de "fábrica", na verdade), e isto está ok, só que o conceito é bem mais amplo que isso.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Por padrão todo método criado em uma classe pertence ao objeto. Isso significa que é necessária uma instância do objeto para se chamar um método, e essa instância é normalmente associada ao primeiro parâmetro da função (que convenciona-se chamar de `self`). Mesmo o método `__init__`, chamado durante a construção do objeto, já assume que o objeto existe e está acessível através do parâmetro `self`.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass # self é o objeto sendo criado
    def bar(self, a, b, d):
        pass # self é o objeto

foo = Foo()
foo.bar(1,2,3) # implicitamente passa "foo" como 1º argumento para "bar"
fn = foo.bar   # fn aqui é um bound method, ligado a "foo"
fn(1,2,3)      # Ainda passa "foo" como 1º argumento para "bar"
```

Para se criar métodos que pertençam **à classe**, e não ao objeto, pode-se usar os decoradores `@staticmethod` ou `@classmethod`. Ambos são semelhantes, embora o primeiro não faça referência alguma à classe e o segundo o faça (de forma semelhante ao método comum, embora nesse caso convenciona-se chamar de `cls` em vez de `self`).

```
class Foo(object):
    @staticmethod
    def bar(a, b, c):
        pass
    @classmethod
    def baz(cls, a, b, c):
        pass

Foo.bar(1,2,3) # Os argumentos são 1, 2 e 3
Foo.baz(1,2,3) # Os argumentos são Foo, 1, 2 e 3

x = Foo() # Também se pode chamar métodos de classe a partir de uma instância
x.bar(1,2,3) # Os argumentos são 1, 2 e 3
x.baz(1,2,3) # Os argumentos são Foo, 1, 2 e 3
```

A principal diferença entre `@classmethod` e `@staticmethod` é que o primeiro pode ser **herdado** de forma a fazer alguma coisa útil. Pois embora ambos sejam "herdáveis", o primeiro pode levar a classe em consideração ao exercer sua função, e o segundo não (pois ele não tem referência para a classe sendo usada).

```
class Foo(object):
    @staticmethod
    def bar():
        print Foo   # Não há referência à classe, então só se pode acessá-la pelo nome
    @classmethod
    def baz(cls):
        pprint cls  # Há referência explícita à classe

class Bar(Foo):
    pass

Bar.bar() # imprime Foo
Bar.baz() # imprime Bar
```

Um método de classe/estático pode ser usado para qualquer coisa, mas faz mais sentido usá-lo para coisas que têm relação com a classe sendo definida (do contrário, por que colocá-lo numa classe, e não diretamente no módulo?). Uma possibilidade é usá-lo como [**fábrica**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padr%C3%A3o_de_projeto_de_software#Padr.C3.B5es_de_cria.C3.A7.C3.A3o), customizando a criação de objetos não necessariamente da mesma classe (por exemplo usando subclasses quando apropriado), ou mesmo quando a classe é a mesma, variando os parâmetros recebidos. Mas há muitas outras. Pessoalmente, não me recordo de situações na qual um método de classe me foi útil [em Python], embora lembre vagamente de já tê-lo utilizado.